# PHP unexpected end of file happens in online testing environment, but doesn't happen in development environment

Tags: php, codeigniter

After I pulled the last code updates to an AWS instance where a test environment is running, a page displayed HTTP Error 500. I'm using CodeIgniter and the AWS instance was set to run as "production" (*SetEnv CI_ENV production* on .htaccess), so I changed that to "development" to display PHP error messagens. That's when I get the following mesage.

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: ParseError
>
> Message: syntax error, unexpected end of file
>
> Filename: /var/www/html/flip/application/views/flip_list.php
>
> Line Number: 58
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /var/www/html/flip/application/controllers/Flip.php
>   Line: 131
>   Function: view
>
> File: /var/www/html/flip/index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

On my localhost environment it does not happen, the page is displayed without errors or warnings.

Localhost is running PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4. And the AWS instance is running PHP 7.0.14 on CentOS. CodeIgniter version is 3.1.3.

I checked flip_list.php and Flip.php, but I didn't find where the problem is.

The controller file (Flip.php) is 350+ lines long, so I'm posting it on a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/agyMuf1T

Below the code of the view (flip_list.php):

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?>
<?php
$first = true;
$second = false;
foreach ($editions->result() as $edition) {
    $edition_hash = $this->flip->encrypt_decrypt_edition_id($edition->edition_id, 'encrypt');

    $date = date_create($edition->edition_date);
    $date = date_format($date, 'd\/m\/Y');

    if( $first ) {
        $first = false;
        $second = true;
    ?>
    <div class="latest">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('flip/'.$slug.'/view/'.$edition_hash); ?>" class="view-edition">
                <img src="<?php echo $edition->edition_cover; ?>" class="edition-cover">
                <span>Edição <?php echo $date; ?></span>
                <span>Número <?php echo $edition->edition_number; ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    else {
    if( $second ) { 
        $second = false;
    ?>
    <div class="editions">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-content-stretch flex-wrap">
    <?
    }
    ?>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="<?php echo base_url('flip/'.$slug.'/view/'.$edition_hash); ?>" class="view-edition">
                <img src="<?php echo $edition->edition_cover; ?>" class="edition-cover">
                <span><?php echo $date; ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
} // foreach
?>
    </div><!-- .d-flex -->
    </div><!-- .editions -->
```

I'd like some help debbuging this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have short tags (http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) disabled on your test server. You have two choices, enable short tags in your php.ini or change `<?` to `<?php`.  It's generally not considered great practice to use short tags, and errors like this are one reason why, so I'd suggest changing your tags to use `<?php`.

I'll post part of the view which has your short tag:

```
 <div class="editions">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-content-stretch flex-wrap">
    <?
    }
    ?>
        <div class="item">
```

Comment: short_open_tag is disabled in both environments. I didn't find any ocurrences of <? opening tags, and I always write them as <?php, I'll search again though.

Comment: There is one in the view you posted: `<div class="d-flex flex-row align-content-stretch flex-wrap">
    <?
    }
    ?>
        <div class="item">`

Comment: Indeed that was the offending opening tag. I updated the code to use <?php and the issue is solved. Many thanks, Pacio!

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected end of file in server may happens as normally live server are on linux. And you may be testing on windows server so while transferring file it may be modified as windows and linux have different mechanism to denote new line. So, set as following(in Filezilla FTP Client): 
Go to `Transfer > Transfer type > select Binary` and again upload all of your view files.

Comment: I avoid running Apache on Windows as much as possible. In this project, in particular, I'm the sole developer coding on a LAMP stack on localhost, the AWS instance also runs Linux, and the code is transfered via git repository. I wasn't aware that this error could happen because of different line endings on Windows though. Thanks, Saroj!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that HEREDOC and NOWDOC syntax is supported in PHP 7.3+. I'm new to PHP development, and I absolutely prefer HEREDOC syntax to the mixed open/close tags.

Later realized that I had version 7.4 running locally and version 7.0 running remotely. There were a couple HEREDOC assignments in my code that were running without issue on my local machine, but I found an "unexpected end of file" error in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` which was showing as a 500 Internal Server Error in the console.

Was super confused by this for a few hours until I was out of ideas and removed the HEREDOCs. Then it worked. Hope this helps someone else. Lesson learned: keep your PHP versions the same in development and production envs.